# Java swing window builder : Jframe resize and setsize problems

Tags: java, swing, windowbuilder

Please help !
I have three problems:

1. The Jframe can't resize.
2. How can I make the frame 100% fit in the design tab ?
3. How can I avoid the following items in the picture to be cropped[image: the following items]

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Toolkit;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class home0504 extends JFrame {

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    home0504 frame = new home0504();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public home0504() {
        //setBounds(100, 100, 392, 328);
        setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH); 
        setSize((int)Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().getWidth(), (int)Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().getHeight());
        setResizable(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    }

}
```

Here's a look in my design tab :
[image]

Comment: 1) Class names SHOULD start with an upper case character. Have you ever seen a class in the Java API that doesn't? Learn and follow Java naming conventions. 2) *The Jframe can't resize.* - because it is shown in the extended state. You need to either a) drag the frame so you can access the resizing border or b) click on the "iconify" icon first.